# Swift UIKit label text doesn't update / view doesn't update

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, uikit

I have a problem:

I have a list of items this is controller A, and when I click on any item I go to controller B (item info), I then execute the `ledLightingButton_Tapped` function by pressing the corresponding button that activates the LED indicator for the animal.

```
    @IBAction func ledLightingButton_Tapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if !GlobalData.shared.led_animals.contains(GlobalData.shared.selectedAnimalId) {
            GlobalData.shared.led_animals.append(GlobalData.shared.selectedAnimalId)
        }
        activateLED(at: GlobalData.shared.selectedAnimalId)
    }

    func activateLED(at animalId: String) {
        ServerSocket.shared?.perform(
            op: "ActivateLED",
            with: [
                "light_duration": "180",
                "led_color": "White",
                "client_data": "",
                "led_animals": [animalId]
            ]
        ) { err, data in
            guard err == nil else { return }
            print(data)
            let ledStatus = data[0]["led_request_status"].stringValue
            self.ledStatusLabel.text = ledStatus
            GlobalData.shared.isActiveLED = true
            self.startTimer()
        }
    }
```

Upon successful activation, the animal number is added to the array, and the `startTimer` is called which every 10 seconds requests `checkLEDStatus` for all animals in the array.

```
    func startTimer() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateCowStatus), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func updateCowStatus() {
        self.checkLEDStatus()
    }

    func checkLEDStatus() {
        ServerSocket.shared?.perform(
            op: "CheckStatusLED",
            with: [
                "light_duration": "180",
                "led_color": "White",
                "client_data": "",
                "led_animals": GlobalData.shared.led_animals
            ]
        ) { err, data in
            guard err == nil else {
                GlobalData.shared.isActiveLED = false
                self.stopTimer()
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                for i in 0..<data.count {
                    if GlobalData.shared.selectedAnimalId == data[i]["animal_id"].stringValue {
                        let ledStatus = data[i]["led_request_status"].stringValue
                        if ledStatus.contains("Fail") {
                            guard let index = GlobalData.shared.led_animals.firstIndex(of: GlobalData.shared.selectedAnimalId) else { return }
                            GlobalData.shared.led_animals.remove(at: index)
                        }
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.ledStatusLabel.text = ledStatus
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The current status of the animal is displayed on the label. If you go in the controller A and activate the status + get a result from checkedLEDstatus - it is work for one animal - everything works, but if you go to controller B, activate for animal number 1, go out and open animal number 2 - perform activation, return to animal number 1 - then the label is no longer is updated, it does not display the new value, but I check it from debugging and property self.ledStatuslabel.text contains new value but UI didn't update. self.ledStatuslabel.text show old value.

Please help me, thanks!

Comment: I tried added `setNeedsDisplay()` after `self.ledStatusLabel.text = ledStatus` - it is useless

Comment: Can you show us images for the issue and what you want to achieve?